# Segmenting column on 4 quantiles

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to create a column where it would tell us in which quantile it is.

Currently I'm doing a groupby on country, industry and bucket and want to segment them into 4 separate segments on another column ratio. I was thinking of doing a quantile into 4 parts and segment them.

I'm currently stuck on how to go about it. Any leads would be highly appreciated.

```
df.groupby(['country', 'industry', 'bucket'])['ratio'].quantile()
```

end result I'm hoping for for example:

```
id    country     industry    bucket    ratio    quantile
1      India       Agri        0-2m      0.05      1
2      USA         IT          15-50m    0.1       2
3      India       Agri        2-15m     0.1       1
4      India       Utilities   2-15m     0.01      3
5      India       Agri        2-15m     0.01      4
.
.
.
```

(for reference)

Comment: did you try `qcut`

Comment: I'd recommend against `qcut` as it might throw an error on duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

`qcut` with `duplicates='drop'` may be able to get you what you need, but I would need additional data to verify this.

```
df['quantile'] = (df.groupby(['country', 'industry', 'bucket'])['ratio']
                    .transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 4, labels=False, duplicates='drop')+1)
                 )
```